# relative path for websockets in boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have known the basic use of boost::asio such as:

```
    std::size_t CacheSize = 1024;
    boost::asio::io_context global_io_context;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket cur_socket(global_io_context);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver cur_resolver(global_io_context);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type cur_endpoints;
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> Cache;
    try
    {
        Cache.resize(CacheSize);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", "82");
        if (cur_endpoints.size() <= 0)
        {
            cur_endpoints = cur_resolver.resolve(query);
        }
        boost::asio::connect(cur_socket, cur_endpoints);
        boost::asio::read(cur_socket, boost::asio::buffer(Cache));
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
```

It works for the url "ws://127.0.0.1:82".

But what I need is to work with "ws://127.0.0.1:82/rav_path"
I have tried the code mentioned above: It connected successfully, but could not receive any data!

Where do I input the '/rav_path'? Or is there any kind of query that I can set the whole url directly rather than set host,service and rav_path separately? like the ClientWebSocket in C#:

```
web = new ClientWebSocket();
var w = web.ConnectAsync(new System.Uri("ws://127.0.0.1:82/rav_path"), CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: you haven't got a websocket, you've just got a raw TCP socket, you need to do some HTTP handshaking before you can actually use the connection, try https://github.com/boostorg/beast

Comment: Get it. I muddled up websocket with raw-tcp.

Answer (score 0):

Using boost::beast like this:

```
...
boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
...
boost::asio::connect(cur_socket.next_layer(), cur_endpoints);
// cur_socket.set_option( ... ) // Optional.

// The HTTP handshaking process mentioned by Alan Birtles( Thank you :)  )
cur_socket.handshake("127.0.0.1:82", "/rav_path"); // The relative path is applied here.

cur_socket.read(buffer);
...
```

[Simple WebSocket Client](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/quick_start/websocket_client.html)